# Why isn't my (very basic) module controller being loaded?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

My file structure is as follows:

- Reckless

  - ContactFormSelectors

    - controllers

      - Contacts

        - IndexController.php
    - etc

      - config.xml
    - Helper

      - Data.php

My IndexController.php file is very simple:

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'here';
        exit;
    }

}
```

I'd expect the output to be a blank page with 'here' output.  This file isn't being loaded at all though, unfortunately.

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
    </modules>
    <frontend>

        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Reckless_ContactFormSelectors before="Mage_Contacts">Reckless_ContactFormSelectors</Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>

    </frontend>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
                <class>Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_Helper</class>
            </Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

I have an XML file in /app/etc/modules/Reckless_ContactFormSelectors.xml with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Logs are empty and hold no clues.

Within System > Configuration > Advanced I can see the module and it is enabled.

Comment: controllers,Block,Helper should be under `Reckless>ContactFormSelectors` folder

Comment: @AmitBera apologies - that was my markdown formatting - it's correct, and I've updated the answer

Comment: You shouldn't have a sub-dir `Contacts` under `controllers` for your `Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_IndexController` unless you name it `Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_Contacts_IndexController` and call the action on the URL "contacts/contacts_index/index"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you configured and named the controller the file should reside directly in `Reckless > ContactFormSelectors > controllers`

Otherwise the definition should have been

```
<Reckless_ContactFormSelectors before="Mage_Contacts">Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_Contacts</Reckless_ContactFormSelectors>
```

and the class name

```
class Reckless_ContactFormSelectors_Contacts_IndexController
```

Comment: Sorry, I was originally using before, not after.  I changed to after to troubleshoot.  I've amended the answer to include 'before' instead.

Comment: the problem was, as you said in the update, my folder structure.  Can you reflect that in the full answer so I can mark correct?

Comment: Updated to resemble the updated question